# How to change the colors of the TableView's rows?

Tags: javafx-2

I have a tableview and want to change the default colors of the rows if I...
1. ... hover above a row.
2. ... selected a row.

Is there a easy way to do all of it in the css-file?

All I found out is that for case 1, I can set

`.table-cell:hover {
    -fx-background-color: green;  }`

in the css-file. With that the color of the cell changes but not the color of the whole row.

`.table-view .row-selection:hover{
    -fx-background-color: lightgreen;  }`
and a lot of other combinations I tried are not working.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
/* Selected row */
.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:filled:focused:selected {
    -fx-background-color: brown;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background: -fx-accent;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-selection-bar-text;
}

/* Selected row when table not focused */
.table-row-cell:filled:focused:selected {
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background: -fx-accent;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-selection-bar-text;
}

/* Row hovered */
.table-view:row-selection .table-row-cell:filled:hover {
    -fx-background-color: green;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-inner-color;
}

/* Selected row hovered */
.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:filled:focused:selected:hover {
    -fx-background: -fx-accent;
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-selection-bar-text;
}

/* Selected row hovered when table not focused */
.table-view:row-selection .table-row-cell:filled:focused:hover {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0, 1 1 2 1, 2 2 3 2, 3 3 4 3;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-inner-color;
}
```

Comment: +1, though I would remove `focused` from the first section so it reads: `.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:filled:selected`. The reason for that is when multiple selection is enabled it only affected the first selected row.