# Whats is the right JavaFX CSS syntax when a class is selected?

Tags: javafx, javafx-css

I have seen the recommended [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746459/how-to-change-the-colors-of-the-tableviews-rows) as below -

```
.A:selected {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

But that didnt work for me. I got it working using -

```
:selected .A {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

Also, what is the syntax to apply the same style for multiple classes when selected? This worked for me, but wanted to know if there is a better/more concise syntax...

```
:selected .A, :selected .B, :selected .C {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: As you mentioned the first one is the recommended one. However I suspect the reason, why it does not work may be in how you apply the style to your node, so you would have to post some code there.

Comment: `.A:selected` will match a node with style class `A` when it is selected, assuming it supports a `selected` pseudoclass. `:selected .A` will match a node with style class `A` that is a descendent in the scene graph of a node that is selected (and that supports the `selected` pseudoclass). So it basically just depends on what you are trying to apply style to. You can check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) to see which pseudoclasses each node type supports.

Comment: Ah thanks, that is useful. What about applying the styles to multiple classes when they are selected? Is my syntax above correct?